# how I filter the input result from some words like kill, gun using simple python if statement

Tags: python

I want to filter the x result to know which category would be appended to

```
def bot():
    kids = []
    adults = [] 
    index = 0
    x = input("enter movie name ")
    for side in x:
        if x == "gun" or x == "kill":
            kids.append(x)
        else:
            adults.append(x)
        print(kids)
        print(adults)
```

what if x == "top gun"  it will ignore it

I need to make it if x has "kill or gun, etc" don't add it to category less than 16 years old recommends

Comment: What do you think `for side in x:` does? And why do you have that statement if you never use the variable `side` later?

Comment: Just use the following python code:  `if "gun" in x:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to compare the individual words. What you are currently doing is iterating over the individual *characters*. To do this comparison word-wise, I recommend using the [`split` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) and iterate over the output of that:

```
movie_name = input('enter movie name: ')
for word in movie_name.split():
    if word in ('gun', 'kill'):
        kids.append(word)
    else:
        adults.append(word)
```